# Reading a part of a txt file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text, filestream

I need to read a txt file part by part...
For example, in a txt file: (age,5char_name)

```
17susan23wilma25fredy
```

I need to read firstly `17susan`. In other words, the first seven characters and after `23wilma` and `25fredy`, but **I'm not reading the whole file and substring the file record.** Is there a way to do this via streamreader?

Records are always seven bytes... 2 bytes for age, 5 bytes for name and all records in a line. There is no jump into the next line.

Comment: It's not clear how the parts of the string are separated from each other and what means `age,5char_name`? Has the age always two-digits and the name always 5? What is the desired result at all? Has the file multiple lines or just one?

Comment: are there any ages in there with 1 digit? or would it display 09 for 9 years old for example?

Comment: Is it always a 7 byte chunk or can it be a 6 byte chunk if you are dealing with a young child, e.g. 4billy

Comment: It is always 7 byte..it is fixed.. age is always 2 bytes name 5 bytes

Comment: and all record in a line there is no jump into next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is the solution:

```
Dim filestream As New FileStream("\records.txt", FileMode.Open)
Dim streamreader As New StreamReader(fs)
Dim buffer(7) As Char
bw.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, 7)
Console.WriteLine(buffer)
```

this is read first 7.. you can read other via loop or for..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a static number of characters per record (seven in your description), you could use a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) reader instead, and use the [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) method to retrieve seven chars at a time.

For example:

```
Const  chunkSize As Integer = 7
Using inputFile = File.OpenRead("namefile.txt")
    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    Dim buffer = New Byte(chunkSize - 1) {}

    bytesRead = inputFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    while bytesRead = 7
            'Process the buffer here
            bytesRead = inputFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End While
End Using
```

(code isn't tested, but should be close)

Comment: How can i restrict for 7 chars for eachtime?

Comment: This is reading *bytes*, not characters. Probably what OP meant, but quite a big and important difference.

Comment: Correct; the OP would need to know how many bytes per character, and set the chunksize appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you ALWAYS want to use the first 7 characters, you can simply use Visual Basic line of code like:

```
Dim Result as String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(string, no)
```

String is the StreamReader line from which you want to read only first seven characters.

No is any integer value and it is equal to the number of characters you want to read, in this case 7.

Also, in the same way, you can use Right and Mid to select a string from the right or somewhere in the middle.